# Intro to Geoprocessing Scripting with Python for ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, geoprocessing

Can you point me to any recommended online resources where i can learn the fundamental basics of geoprocessing scripting and the different modules/python has available for an ArcGIS environment.

I have tried querying the web, but most of the time it links to me to ESRI's geoprocessing training course which I have been trying to get into through my job.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53816/what-are-some-resources-for-learning-arcpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESRI has a variety of free web-based courses.  One that may meet your requirements is called [Python for Everyone](http://training.esri.com/gateway/index.cfm?fa=catalog.webcoursedetail&courseid=2520).  The course addresses the following subjects:

> - Choose the Python scripting environment that meets your needs.
> - Choose appropriate data types and apply Python syntax rules when    writing a script.
> - Quickly create a script to automate a geoprocessing task using a    Python snippet.
> - Label map features using a Python expression.
> - Understand common types of errors that can occur in a script and how    to correct them.

You can access all of the free training session at the [ESRI training catalog](http://training.esri.com/gateway/index.cfm?fa=search.results&cannedsearch=2).  I would also recommend the book [Programming ArcGIS 10.1 with Python Cookbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1849694443).

Comment: What level of proficiency in Python in general you think is needed before one can really be efficient in using ArcPy and other useful modules?

Comment: For me, it took about a year working with Python before I felt proficient.  However, even after a few weeks I was able to accomplish much more than I would have otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

In general, their resource page:

[What is ArcPy?](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/What_is_ArcPy/000v000000v7000000/)

[A quick tour of geoprocessing tool references](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_geoprocessing_tool_references/002t0000000z000000/) (has python code snippets for each tool)

Also, check out this book:

[Python Scripting for ArcGIS](http://esripress.esri.com/display/index.cfm?fuseaction=display&websiteID=224&moduleID=0)