# Building a tool to both geocode and do topology check on the geocoded point (ArcGIS)

Tags: arcpy, geocoding, topology

Never built a tool in ArcGIS. Would someone tell me if it's feasible to create a single tool (preferably using Python) which:

- Geocodes an address
- Checks to see if geocoded point falls within a boundary
- Notifies user if point does or does not fall within boundary

Is there any advice on resources to consult, or ways to go about a solution as this is outside my realm of experience?

Answer (score 4):

To geocode an address, you need to have a [geocoding locator](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/geocoding/finding-an-address-about.htm). Your options are:

- buying [Esri StreetMap Premium](http://www.esri.com/data/streetmap/product-matrix) geocoding locators from Esri (ready to use in ArcGIS);
- buying TomTom MultiNet / HERE PointAddressing and building your own geocoding locator (will need to learn quite a lot before being to build);
- getting [ArcGIS Online organization subscription](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/geocoding/working-with-arcgis-online-geocoding-service.htm) which provides access to the online geocoding locator.

Good to know that it's free to search for an address inside ArcMap by using the [Find tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/using-the-find-tool.htm) on the Tools toolbar. This doesn't create a point feature but rather a graphic, however [graphic can be converted to a feature](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/page-layouts/converting-between-graphics-and-features-convertin.htm). These things are not exposed in arcpy (Python package in ArcGIS), however, maybe a manual process will be sufficient, so I wanted to point this out.

If you want to handle this outside of ArcGIS, you could check the [geopy](https://github.com/geopy/geopy), a geocoding library for Python.

You would build a [custom script tool in Python](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/a-quick-tour-of-creating-script-tools.htm) that geocodes an input address either by accessing a local geocoding locator or by sending the request to the Internet server and handling the response.

Checking whether a point is inside a poly can be done with [Select Layer By Location](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-layer-by-location.htm) geoprocessing tool tool or by accessing the [`arcpy.Geometry()`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/geometry.htm) methods. Telling user whether it's inside the boundary can be done either in the dialog box of the running tool or as a message box window.

The whole workflow you describe might fit well into a [Python add-in](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/python-addins/creating-an-add-in-tool.htm): user enters an address into an input text box and a message window pop-ups with the feedback.

Learn more about [Python in ArcGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53816/what-are-some-resources-for-learning-arcpy).