# Replacing characters after certain word in Python parser of ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I have a table with field which contains path to database. The same thing in this field will be the extension of file.
Here is how it looks like

```
D:\Проекты\Москва для тестов\Test.gdb\graf_fd
```

I need to have this

```
D:\Проекты\Москва для тестов\Test.gdb\
```

Probably I should replace everything after 'gdb\'. I know that I can type something like delete last 7 charachters, but the name of dataset can be another in other databases as well as the length of string data before 'gdb\'. So are there codes for removing or replacing the characters after certain word?

Comment: Even though you have a file geodatabase in your pathname, your pathname is simply a string, so the answer to this is pure Python (best researched at [so]) rather than ArcPy (best researched here at [gis.se]).

Comment: @PolyGeo, I believe Pavel wants to achieve this using ArcMap and field calculator even though you would need pure Python to split a string. Sounds like a GIS.SE question to me :) Please open it up so I could post an answer :)

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov вы правы)

Comment: @AlexTereshenkov I've re-opened it but I do think this is one that falls on the [so] side of the Python/ArcPy line.  To help ArcPy users become more proficient in Python I think we should always remind them of the enormous Python resource that is [so].

Comment: @PolyGeo, I hear you, chief. Agreed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided you have two fields in the feature class, `LongPath` and `ShortPath`. Both are of `Text` type.

To calculate the `ShortPath` field, right-click the field name in the attribute table and choose `Field Calculator`, switch to `Python` parser and run:

`'\\'.join(!LongPath!.split('\\')[:-1])`

This will construct a string path with all parts except the last one.

```
LongPath                                        ShortPath
D:\Проекты\Москва для тестов\Test.gdb\graf_fd   D:\Проекты\Москва для тестов\Test.gdb
D:\Проекты\Москва для тестов\Test.gdb\graf_fd   D:\Проекты\Москва для тестов\Test.gdb
```

More readings on Python used here:

[`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

Comment: that works! Thank you so much! I defiftely should get some knowledge about Python :)

Comment: @PavelPereverzev, no problem at all. Yeah, Python can be very handy. Check this post out with the resources to learn compiled, great one - http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53816/what-are-some-resources-for-learning-arcpy