# Recommended Books on Arcpy/Python and GIS

Tags: arcpy, references

Does anyone have recommendations on books/workbooks that I can read that goes beyond a beginner's level for Arcpy/Python with GIS?  I've written several scripts, some simple, some complex, but I want to learn how to be more efficient, and how to look at my code and improve upon it. I learn best interactive workbooks, so I'm looking for a learning medium like that.

Comment: Make sure to look at the https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53816/learning-arcpy