# Populating set using for loop

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I am attempting to create a single set of all the attributes read from a field on a feature class.  This is my code so far:

```
import arcpy
workspace = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor("FireStations",['CITY'])
s1 = set()

for row in cursor:
    s1.add(row)
    print(s1)
```

The issue I am having is that it seems to create a new set with all the attributes within the field for every new attribute.  So instead of one single set of all the attributes I get one set with all the attributes for every row in the specified field. I know this is most likely an issue with my for loop, anyone have any thoughts on fixing this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get all the unique values from a field, you could use a set comprehension on the `SearchCursor`:

```
import arcpy
workspace = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
unique_values = {r[0] for r in arcpy.da.SearchCursor("FireStations", ['CITY'])}
print(unique_values)
```

Alternatively, if you would still like to use a `for` loop, you would need to use the `set.add()` method. Python sets have never had `append` method. Mind the indentation of the `print()` - you would most likely want to print the output set of unique values just once. Also, each `row` would be a tuple with of length 1 meaning you would need to access the actual value using the index - in this case `row[0]` as indexing in Python starts with `0`.

```
import arcpy
workspace = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor("FireStations", ['CITY'])
s1 = set()

for row in cursor:
    s1.add(row[0])
print(s1)
```

Comment: yes you're right .add not .append.  Also can't believe I missed that my print function was inside the for loop, thanks a lot.

Comment: No worries, glad it worked out! Finding issues in the code and fixing them is part of programming, too! :) good luck with learning arcpy! There is a great collection of resources - make sure to review them - excellent bedtime reading ;) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53816/learning-arcpy

Comment: Also recommend a book https://www.amazon.com/dp/1589483715/ - going through this one will give you 99% of what you could possibly need.